# Calculating PSI generated by water entraining air as it flows down a pipe

Tags: gravity, pressure, water, air

This is the concept used in a trompe.  Basically, the idea is that if we allow water to flow down a pipe and if that pipe has inclined air intake orifices near the top where the water enters, then the water will entrain air bubbles down into a reservoir where the air bubbles can then escape the downward pressure of water releasing compressed air in the reservoir while the water escapes through an exit pipe.  I would like to know how water is capturing air when it is pulled by gravity down a tube and what variables determine how much air will be captured.  Here is a video describing the overall concept if interested:  [Trompe Concept Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SScpJMsCm9c).

[image: a simple trompe]

Comment: Hi, I don't know if you ever found your answer. If you did could you publish it? I am no expert in formulas and read this stuff long ago, but if there is any place you would be able to find this I would say it is in this article https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015078460238&view=1up&seq=5